# Required Field Validator Not Working with AjaxControlToolkit

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, requiredfieldvalidator

This is my code

```
<div>
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Employee ID
                </td>
                <td>:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmployeeID" runat="server" />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="!" SetFocusOnError="true"  EnableClientScript="true" ControlToValidate="txtEmployeeID" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Name of the Company Placed
                </td>
                <td>:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNameoftheCompanyPlaced" runat="server" />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="!" SetFocusOnError="true"  EnableClientScript="true" ControlToValidate="txtNameoftheCompanyPlaced" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Third Party Name
                </td>
                <td>:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtThirdPartyName" runat="server" />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="!" SetFocusOnError="true"  EnableClientScript="true" ControlToValidate="txtThirdPartyName" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Third Party Email ID
                </td>
                <td>:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtThirdPartyEmailID" runat="server" />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="!" SetFocusOnError="true"  EnableClientScript="true" ControlToValidate="txtThirdPartyEmailID" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Third Party Mobile No
                </td>
                <td>:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtThirdPartyMobileNo" runat="server" />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="!" SetFocusOnError="true"  EnableClientScript="true" ControlToValidate="txtThirdPartyMobileNo" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Third Party Mail Received Date
                </td>
                <td>:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtThirdPartyMailReceivedDate" runat="server" />
                    <ajax:CalendarExtender ID="ajaxThirdPartyMailReceivedDate" TargetControlID="txtThirdPartyMailReceivedDate" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Third Party Mail Reverted Date
                </td>
                <td>:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtThirdPartyMailRevertedDate" runat="server" />
                    <ajax:CalendarExtender ID="ajaxtThirdPartyMailRevertedDate" TargetControlID="txtThirdPartyMailRevertedDate" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>No. of Times Verification Done Count 1
                </td>
                <td>:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNoOfTimesVerificationDoneCount1" runat="server" />
                </td>
                <td>Count 1 Date
                </td>
                <td>:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCount1Date" runat="server" />
                    <ajax:CalendarExtender ID="ajaxCount1Date" TargetControlID="txtCount1Date" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>No. of Times Verification Done Count 2
                </td>
                <td>:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="NoOfTimesVerificationDoneCount2" runat="server" />
                </td>
                <td>Count 2 Date
                </td>
                <td>:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCount2Date" runat="server" />
                    <ajax:CalendarExtender ID="ajaxCount2Date" TargetControlID="txtCount2Date" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>No. of Times Verification Done Count 3
                </td>
                <td>:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNoOfTimesVerificationDoneCount3" runat="server" />
                </td>
                <td>Count 3 Date
                </td>
                <td>:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCount3" runat="server" />
                    <ajax:CalendarExtender ID="ajaxCount3" TargetControlID="txtCount3" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="Subimt" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

and the page behind code is:

```
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblError.Text = "no code";
    }
```

when I click on the submit button, I'm getting both the label error and the requiredfield validatiors

I'm getting output something like this:

[image]

I dont want to hit the submit event behind the code by using Requiredfield validators

Comment: Do you use update panels? If so, which part of your markup is in it?

Comment: @Andrei: OP is using `ajax:CalendarExtender` so for this `ScriptManager` is required. I believe that OP isn't using any updatepanel.

Comment: Adding `EnableClientScript="true"` is not necessary by default it's always `true`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem in witch adding a ScriptManager to a page broke the RequiredFieldValidator validation.  The solution I found was to add some ScriptReferences to the ScriptManager.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
         <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

You ScriptReference Path and Names may differ from mine.